# CMS existing HTML5/CSS3 website

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I build HTML5/CSS3 websites that are cross-browser compliant and responsive. My clients want the ability to edit text areas and upload new stories into the news section and images to the photo gallery. What is my best option to continue building (clean, SEO friendly) websites while giving my clients the option to update the website themselves?

I have looked into the likes of a CMS like joomla and drupal and they seem heavily dependent on templates which scares me. Is it just a case of pasting my php-includes and css files into system that builds my unique 'template'? Other CMS options; cushycms and pagelime seem more along the lines of what I'm looking for but appear to edit existing text only?

In a nutshell; I want to keep my existing designs and simply make them editable.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the blatant self-promotion, but feel I have to chime in.

I'm the CEO of [Webpop](http://www.webpop.com), a fully hosted CMS that's made with frontend developers and web designers in mind.

We built Webpop exactly for solving this problem and have done a lot of work on making sure that you can keep your HTML/CSS and javascript exactly as it appears in your static mockup when building a site with Webpop.

We have two completely separate UIs, one for you, where we've done our best to make it as easy as we can to let you work directly with the HTML, CSS and javascript. And one for your clients, that's just a simple on-site editor where they can update the part of the site that's dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for a MVC framework. You can find all information about all different frameworks [here](http://www.phpframeworks.com/).

The advantage of this is that you can keep your HTML5/CSS3 as the "views" while moving the business logic to controllers and models of your MVC framework. I personally used CakePHP and CodeIgniter. The latter is very easy to use and will be very simple to set up.

Answer (score 0):

I have found Get Simple CMS http://get-simple.info/ to be great for this.  It PHP based but doesn't require a database.  It comes with a few templates, but it's not too tricky to edit or create your own template from your CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I always liked Perch for exactly this kind of stuff. Editable fields, real simple stuff. However I eventually did migrate to Wordpress, simply because my clients started demanding more blog-life features. If the sites you build are going to remain simple, Perch is quite wonderful.

http://grabaperch.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well basically i always use wordpress , it's not so hard to learn... you slice your site up into the areas you need ... the menu's are generated automatically as you add pages to your site . Wordpress also has lots of plug-ins wich are easy to implement . Wordpress is not only a blog , major sites use it for contentmanaging their website.
check it out at [Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/) for learning to slice up your website there's a very nice guide, find it here : [Theming and CSS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Blog_Design_and_Layout)